# Programa em c++ trava quando uso uma função para pegar o nome de um arquivo

Tags: c++, char

Estou fazendo uma pequena IDE em c++ e estou com problemas na hora de pegar o nome  de um arquivo.
ex:
o caminho completo do arquivo é "keywords//cplusplus.txt"
porém o nome do arquivo é "cplusplus.txt".
Por isso escrevi uma função para pegar o verdadeiro nome.

```
char* Io::GetRealName(int file)
{
    char* full_name=GetName(file);
    int last_bar=0;
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(full_name);i++)
    {
        if(full_name[i]=='/')
        {
            last_bar=i+1;
        }
    }
    char* real_name=(char*) malloc((strlen(full_name)-last_bar)*sizeof(char));
    memcpy (real_name,full_name+last_bar,strlen(full_name));
    real_name[strlen(full_name)-last_bar]='\0';
    return real_name;
}
```

A função GetName(int) pega o caminho completo do arquivo.
Não sei o que há de errado, pois quando eu acabei a função estava dando certo,
entretanto, depois de um tempo começou a travar e agora algumas vezes trava e outras não.
Alguém sabe o que está errado?
Os ponteiros talvez?

Comment: Porque não escreve tudo em C++ para ficar mais fácil, talvez o erro suma sozinho.

Comment: Não sei ao certo as vezes prefiro usar char* ao invés de string por exemplo, depende da situação. Nesse caso não dá pra mudar porque já tem outras funções que dependem do char*.

Answer (score 2):

O problema está nesta linha de código:

```
memcpy (real_name,full_name+last_bar,strlen(full_name));
```

A função `memcpy` está copiando bytes a mais, ou seja, a função está escrevendo fora da memória alocada por `malloc`. O certo seria assim:

```
memcpy(real_name, full_name+last_bar,(strlen(full_name)-last_bar)*sizeof(char));
```

Agora sim, a quantidade de bytes sendo copiado é o mesmo do que foi alocado em `malloc`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta user72726, não tinha percebido esse erro. confundi o o ultimo parâmetro com posição ao invés de tamanho.      void * memcpy ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );          Porém mesmo colocando o tamanho ainda dá erro, e eu tenho certeza que vem dessa função Io.GetRealName(int), vou continuar tentando.

Comment: @gamedoido, qual o erro que está aparecendo? Adiciona uma descrição do erro no fim da pergunta, e altera o código já que você fez mudanças nele